# Django forms not uploading in the template

Tags: python, django

Django forms not rendiring in the index page but when I created a new html file then it worked

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegisterForCourse(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegisterForCourse
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'subject', 'phone']
```

**view.py**

```
def about_course(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForCourse(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            subject = form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
            messages.success(request, f'you have been successfully registered for {subject}')
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForCourse()
    return render(request, 'goal/index.html', {'form':form})
```

**in index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'about' %}" method="POST" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}  
</form>
```

any idea? It needs to work in index page what am I missing?

Comment: Did you import the form under views.py or not?

Comment: Your index.html contains only the form? Or does it contain any other elements that are rendered and just the form is missing? Could it be that yoy placed your index.html in the wrong folder? Or did you put the new html in the same folder?

Comment: Trstenjak there are other elements in index but there is only one form that should be rendered

Comment: @Anoop Kumar yes I imported

Comment: Please make sure the location of  the template file is in appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check below flow

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm): #Classname

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

**in views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm # Add form which is written in your forms.py
def index(request):
    form = UserForm() #Initiate 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'about' %}" method="POST" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Comment: Dear Anoop Kumar there is no if statement in here or should i include on my own?

Comment: You can can include according to your requirement

Comment: make sure to add the class name in views.py file

Comment: sorry Anoop Kumar it is not working. is there another way?

Comment: please check the directory structure. I think problem is with your directory structure. I am using the https://prnt.sc/ld12od structure.

Comment: finally Anoop Kumar there is mistake in directory structure now i have corrected it is working. Thank you!

Comment: It's my pleasure